# I can't get my USB Mic to work with DaVinci Resolve 18.2 on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: alsa, 23.04, davinci-resolve

I'm trying to get my microphone working for a few weeks now...

Using Resolve 18.6.2 Build 2 and Ubuntu 23.04 with default sound setup (I believe this is pipewire on top of ALSA)

Playback in Resolve works fine, I can switch output in Ubuntu and it works. mic (USB Mozos) works in all other apps like Audacity. In DaVinci input setup I have 8 ALSA inputs and each and every of them produces a sad, flat line.

Could you please hint me where to dig?

Thanks in advance,
Tomek